# Rich editor faster than Microsoft Word?

Tags: text-editors

With Microsoft Word, I regularly wait 2 full seconds () to go from the Table of contents to the document paragraph.
The software feels slow in general. I prefer Notepad++, but it doesn't do automatic Table of Content, as far as I understand, nor rich editing (by which I mean: Heading 1 / Heading 2 etc formatting, colors, etc).

Does anyone know of a fast rich text editor to replace Microsoft Word?

Comment: I can't recommend anything.. but have you tried LibreOffice or OpenOffice? Or maybe it is due to your computer being fairly slow? Have you tried doing what you do on a different computer?

Comment: @Darius I have Windows XP on a Intel Core i5 CPU, M 560 @ 2.67GHz, 3 GB of RAM; I don't think it is slow (Notepad++ is very fast for example; I understand it's lighter but I don't need so many features: just automatic Table of Content mostly).

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I really like LaTeX. However I also know there's a lot of people who don't like it since it's not a WYSIWYG editor. If you want to try LaTeX but stick to the WYSIWYG philosophy, maybe try [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/). LyX somewhat limits LaTeX in what it's capable of (in my opinion), but it's a good starting point...

Answer (score 1):

You could stay with Notepad++ and use [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) plus [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).

Markdown WYSIWYG editing can be done via [Stackedit](http://benweet.github.io/stackedit/).

Notepad++ is restricted to edit pure text files without formatting and layout. However, if you edit page description languages like HTML, [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) or Markdown, you get a properly layouted document in the end. But it takes an additional rendering step.

Comment: Thanks. Can you confirm which one of these tools can generate an automatic Table of Content (based on pre-specified headings)?

Comment: Markdown needs an external extension for ToC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721944/automatic-toc-in-github-flavoured-markdown  In LaTeX ToC is available right away. http://texblog.org/2013/04/29/latex-table-of-contents-list-of-figurestables-and-some-customizations/